# What's the best way to test Facebook Install event?

Tags: facebook, installation

I'm creating an Android game. I'm using Voodoo's Tiny Sauce SDK which comes with Facebook SDK. I have a problem when all my devices are sending Activate App event to Facebook Event Manager, but there are no Install events.
I think it's because once I've managed to set up the SDKs properly to test the Install events, all of my devices had the game on them already and Facebook just won't see them suitable for registering the Install event.

Right now I'm running short of friends with spare phones to test the event.

Is there a way to test the Installation event on the same device? Or every time I install the game on the device and don't get the Install event due to some error the device is marked as "tainted"?

Or should I delete the app from the facebook and make a new one there with new app ID hoping Facebook will see it as an absolutely new app?

I was adding SDK step by step and tested other events on my devices. Once I've tried to test the install event, which was implemented as a last step, the device won't send the Install event while they're sending Activate App events just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create new app in Facebook to make installation events appear. Must've been an error in the app setup.